# Multimeter reading discrepancy on output of HV converter circuit

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, multimeter

I am trying to measure the high DC voltage after it is converted from 5 V to 3 kV through the EMCO AG30 voltage converter. I set the PWM output from the Arduino to 255, so theoretically the voltage after conversion should be 3 kV. However, when I measure the voltage between the 5 kΩ resistor, I read a voltage of 0.018 V which if converted x10^5 is 1.8 kV. Why? I tested it with a different EMCO HV converter and it still is the same. The 5 kΩ is too small to have a noticeable change on the voltage reading so I don't know what's causing the wrong reading. The circuit diagram shown below [image]

I'm a rookie to electrical engineering.

Comment: What is the resistance of your meter? Let’s say it is a moving coil meter and its resistance is 5k ohms. That would give you a 50% error as the meter’s resistance forms part of the resistor divider.

Comment: 18mV is very small, I wouldn't trust a typical voltmeter to be accurate down there. Try using a resistor ratio that provides a few *volts* to be measured instead of a few millivolts. Also, I'm not sure that this device is supposed to be powered with a PWM source. Input power supply voltage should be steady, and the output should be modulated using the control input, which is intended to be an *analogue* potential between 0V and the power supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

A "binary chop" approach, where you split the problem into halves, often pays dividends.

Start by powering the converter directly from 5V with the control input pulled to 5V, and with no load.

Does this give the reading you expect?

If it does, then two obvious potential issues:

- you have an issue with the control loop / PWM.  As others have noted, the module isn't supposed to be driven with PWM on the power input, you should instead apply a smoothed control voltage to the control input. Try direct power connection, and control with a pot.
- the load you are applying exceeds the output capability of the converter.  Verify the expected load compared with the spec sheet, and/or measure the current in the HV return lead. Retry with PWM control but no load.

If it doesn't, consider the options:

- you have a bad batch of converters (seems unlikely given my past excellent experience with EMCO converters)
- your measurement approach is wrong.  As several people have noted in comments, if you are using an analogue meter, the load of the meter may well have a significant impact on the divider.  It would also be worth you decreasing the divider ratio, to give a larger measurement voltage. 1:1000 would give you a 3V signal, which is much easier to measure accurately with a range of meters.

Key is to take actions/measurements which help localize the issue(s).